# Laravel APP_KEY for long term enrypted data (not only passwords)

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-5

Lets say that i need to have all the users entered data encrypted in my db and i am doing it like this:

```
Crypt::encrypt($request['content'])
```

Lets assume that my site will live and prosper for many years with many users and many many gb of encrypted user data.

Does this mean that i have to be absolutely sure that i don't loose my app_key which is in my .env file?

The only thing i could do if my key is compromised is to only decrypt and encrypt with a new key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very right.

Laravel is using AES encryption and exact key is needed for decryption of data.

If you ever want to decrypt your data again then you need the encryption key.

In Laravel implementation it is not possible to simply change the key. If key is changed then you need to reencrypt your data.

Comment: And if i loose it, i will have to run away from my users. Understood.